# NSURLConnection's didCancelAuthenticationChallenge delegate method never called

Tags: cocoa, delegates, protocols, nsurlconnection

Why is that NSURLConnection's didCancelAuthenticationChallenge delegate method is never called, even after manually cancelling the Auth challenge (which in fact gets cancelled as supposed) ?

I paste some bits of the relevant code below, keep in mind that all other delegate methods are called as supposed EXCEPT for `- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didCancelAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge`

Thanks for any help.
//Diego

```
...
NSURLConnection *serviceConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:serviceRequest delegate:self];
...
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
    NSUserDefaults *ud = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if ([challenge previousFailureCount]) {
        NSLog(@"Invalid credentials... Cancelling.");
        [[challenge sender] cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
            // AT THIS POINT cancelAuthenticationChallenge HAS BEEN CALLED, YET, DELEGATE METHOD IS NOT CALLED.
    } else {
        if ([ud stringForKey:@"username"] && [ud stringForKey:@"password"]) {
            NSLog(@"Service is trying to login with locally stored user and password from NSUserDefaults");
            NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:[ud stringForKey:@"username"]
                                                                     password:[ud stringForKey:@"password"]
                                                                  persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];
            [[challenge sender]useCredential:credential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
        } else {
            [delegate STServiceNeedsLoginInfo:self];
        }
    }
}




- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didCancelAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
    NSLog(@"Failed login with status code: %d", [(NSHTTPURLResponse*)[challenge failureResponse]statusCode]);
    // THIS METHOD IS NEVER CALLED. WHY ?
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe that delegate method is provided for if the connection cancels authentication, not you. e.g. if you took too long responding to a challenge, the connection could theoretically cancel auth.

Comment: Yes Mike, some people seems to agree with you, and some other like me thinks that it is a bug, the documentation even contradicts itself many times, so I've posted a bug report to apple and let's see what they say. Thanks!